# installing kvm on centos 6.2 getting error: virsh sysinfo error: failed to get sysinfo

Tags: kvm-virtualization, centos6.2

```
# virsh sysinfo
error: failed to get sysinfo
error: unsupported configuration: Host SMBIOS information is not available

# virsh -c qemu:///system sysinfo
error: failed to get sysinfo
error: unsupported configuration: Host SMBIOS information is not available
```

Following this tutorial to the letter: http://eduardo-lago.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-install-kvm-and-libvirt-on.html

Everything else works fine except this command: virsh sysinfo outputs error.

Help!

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem. My point is your user doesn't have the proper rights.

You could use:

```
 sudo virsh sysinfo
```

Comment: A hash command prompt in the OP was not **that** subtle, really.